# Using JAXB in Eclipse to generate classes from XSD file, how do I ensure imported XSDs end up in a separate package?

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, xsd

I have two schemas that I want to generate classes from. Each schema imports a common schema.

The schema source directories are:

- common/types.xsd
- component/componentType.xsd
- deployment/deployment.xsd

The latter two schemas import the first. Each schema has its own namespace, obviously. I would like each schema to end up in its own package with the types classes existing only in the common package. Every time I try it at the moment I get duplicated common classes. I have tried using a binding specification but without success, it just seems to be ignored.  I tried the following:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <jxb:bindings namespace="http://www.myorg.com/schemas/types" schemaLocation="common/types.xsd" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.myorg.xml.common"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings namespace="http://www.myorg.com/schemas/types" schemaLocation="component/componentType.xsd" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.myorg.xml.common"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I am using Eclipse Juno and I have previously been generating the classes using "New"->"JAXB Classes from Schema". I am not using any custom build scripts etc. for the project, not only that, but I'm afraid that my limited knowledge of building means that understanding or writing custom Ant/Maven scripts is beyond me.

Could someone possibly describe how to generate the classes such that the common classes are shared and using the Eclipse GUI "JAXB Classes from Schema"?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you try use XJC from the command line. Its simple to use and will probably give you a more detailed error description. The command is `xjc path/to/schema/dir -b bindingfile`.